# Why is onKey() called twice?

Tags: android

I am using this code:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
String message = msg.getText().toString();
            if(keyCode == 66)
            {
                //It's hitting here twice.          
            }
            return false;
        };
```

Can anyone please tell me why it's hitting twice when I press enter?

Comment: Once down, once up? Try onKeyDown() or onKeyUp(), or check KeyEvent.getAction().

Answer (score 234, accepted):

OnKey is fired twice: the first time for key down, and the second time for key up, so you have to filter:

```
YOUR_VIEW.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {                           
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                //This is the filter
                if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    return true;

                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 : 
                    MakeToast(1);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 : 
                    MakeToast(2);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3 : 
                    MakeToast(3);
                    break;

                }

                return true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Does returning true or false have any meaning to the super classes?

Comment: You should return false on keys that are not processed?

Comment: Apparently it should be `return false` for keys not processed. I put this code in and when the `EditText` has focus my app stop responding to back button...

Comment: Doing this will stop listening keyevent dpad_center as onClick

Comment: Thanks for `event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, but I return `false` in this case. If `true`, any other keys will be consumed. You even won't exit your activity/fragment with Back button!

Answer (score 6):

```
 itemView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
     //code here
    }
    return false;
  }
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                switch (i) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        if (!HelperFunction.isStringEmpty(edittext.getText().toString())) {

                            if (loadCount == 0) {

                                loadCount ++;


                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

this code block prevents calling the code twice. I use loadCount String value , if loadCount == 0 run my code block and i am doing loadCount ++ in my if block. So My Code block work on time.

Comment: Consider providing an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: This is just a hack and not proper way.