# Android: onKeyListener simulating two instances of a pressed key

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [public boolean onKey() called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802887/public-boolean-onkey-called-twice)

```
Display.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
             case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                solveExpression();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I'm trying to solve the expression contained within the Display(EditText), by pressing the enter button on the keyboard, yet it always interprets it as though I pressed the button twice.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I am not an android guy, but the code looks good to me. Please check which is keyCode (is it 66)?

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
Display.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {    
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                // Check for ACTION_DOWN only...
                if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                    solveExpression();
                    return true;
                }
        }
    }
});
```

The 'action' can be `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_MULTIPLE` (the last being for when a key is pressed and held). onKey() will be called for any/all of those actions.

As the other answer mentions, it's triggering twice because it's once for down and once for up.

Comment: returning true only on `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` will trigger many debug outputs in logcat: `ACTION_DOWN but key is already down and this event is not a key repeat.`

Comment: Doing this will stop listening keyevent dpad_center as onClick

Comment: @ArmasCyndromic Notice the question - this WAS the target.

Comment: @gangus true :) please answer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474607/android-onkeylistener-with-filter-stop-onitemclicklistener-from-dpad

Answer (score 2):

```
if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) // we catch only key down events
    return true;
```

Thus you stop listening other keyevents as onClick.

If you want nobody else further in chain to get the event for another piece of work, you should set

```
    return false;
```

Comment: Doing this will stop listening keyevent dpad_center as onClick

Comment: @ArmasCyndromic Exactly. And  the problem set in the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

not an android guy either but the fact that it registers twice makes me think that OnKey encompasses a onKeyDown and onKeyUp.  Would listening to onKeyUp work for you as well?