# android OnkeyListener with filter stop onItemClicklistener from DPAD

Tags: android, android-dialog, onitemclicklistener, d-pad, onkeylistener

This is my custom-dialog layout.
[image]

I want to move the selector of days and load respective items in the grid below it.

I could perform it via filter as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802887/why-is-onkey-called-twice)

But because of the filter I am not being able to perform the action that should be triggered while clicking items in the grid view. It works fine when I click via mouse but not D-Pad.
If I remove the filter in keyevent, it works normally, but problem again in sliding the selector via.

As I am working in STB, I have no option except remote as remote functionality is kept as the basic requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by using the filter in every case of key-event rather than at top.